# Stability of fixed points - Differential equations

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fixed-point-theorems

I have been looking at this past exam question for a while and I'm unsure how to answer:
$$x ̇= r^2x−x^5,r ∈ {\rm I\!R}$$

a) Find the fixed points of the equation 
b) Determine the stability of the fixed points

I know you have to set the equation equal to zero, and I feel as though I'm being quite dense in not being able to answer this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use $$r^2x-x^5=0$$ and this is the case when $$x(r^2-x^4)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Imposing $\dot x=0$ you get five solutions, $x=0$, $x=\pm \sqrt{r}$ and $x=\pm\sqrt{-r}$. These are the 5 fixed points.

To know their stability, substitute $x=x_0+\epsilon$ into the equation, where $x_0$ is a fixed point and $\epsilon$ is very small. Then linearize the equation in $\epsilon$. The resulting approximate equation will tell you the stability. If it tends to make $\epsilon$ grow, the point is unstable. If if tends to make $\epsilon$ decrease, it is stable.